# Ubuntu 12.04.2 and openni_launch not detecting Kinect after update?

Tags: kinect, linux, openni, ubuntu, ubuntu-precise

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A few days ago I tested my brand new Kinect for XBOX 360 with my laptop after installing ROS Fuerte (with all TurtleBot packages/stacks) and installing the OpenNI/NITE files for the [tracker workaround](http://answers.ros.org/question/42654/openninite-incompatible-in-fuerteprecise/).  Previously it worked, but after doing an update at some point, openni_launch (or even turtlebot_bringup kinect.launch) no longer detects the Kinect.

```
[ INFO] [1365810419.625569068]: [/openni_launch] No devices connected.... waiting for devices to be connected
[ INFO] [1365810420.627682000]: [/openni_launch] No devices connected.... waiting for devices to be connected
[ INFO] [1365810421.629791791]: [/openni_launch] No devices connected.... waiting for devices to be connected
[ INFO] [1365810422.634639075]: [/openni_launch] No devices connected.... waiting for devices to be connected
[ INFO] [1365810423.639501828]: [/openni_launch] No devices connected.... waiting for devices to be connected
```

Yet, lsusb sees the three devices:

```
djtubig-malicex@djtubig-aspire:~$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1bcf:2c18 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 0409:005a NEC Corp. HighSpeed Hub
Bus 001 Device 010: ID 045e:02ad Microsoft Corp. Xbox NUI Audio
Bus 001 Device 009: ID 045e:02b0 Microsoft Corp. Xbox NUI Motor
Bus 001 Device 011: ID 045e:02ae Microsoft Corp. Xbox NUI Camera
```

Given it works under Windows (and even detects in Ubuntu via VMWare albeit no image since that doesn't work), I'm puzzled as to why this suddenly does not wish to be detected by the launcher.

Any advice for someone on 12.04.2?  Thanks.  I'm running out of ideas (and patience with inconsistent documentation around)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60562/ubuntu-12.04.2-and-openni_launch-not-detecting-kinect-after-update?/) by [djtubig-malicex](https://answers.ros.org/users/4667/djtubig-malicex/) on ROS Answers with karma: 176 on 2013-04-12

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [CarolineQ](https://answers.ros.org/users/4109/carolineq/) on 2013-04-15**:
I have the same problem than you, and didn't find any solution for the moment. If you find something, please share it...

**Comment by [Stephane.M](https://answers.ros.org/users/3548/stephane.m/) on 2013-04-15**:
Try uninstalling NITE (by using the ./uninstall) and reinstalling it. It has to be the old version of NITE (1.5.2 if I remember correctly). Let us know....

**Comment by [djtubig-malicex](https://answers.ros.org/users/4667/djtubig-malicex/) on 2013-04-15**:
Already tried that, and I'm already using the old version.  No dice. :(

**Comment by [Stephane.M](https://answers.ros.org/users/3548/stephane.m/) on 2013-04-15**:
If I were you, I would go to 12.10 then. But do a fresh install, updating is really not working well in the case of ROS/kinect/general stuff... I know this solution is a bit long, but it's what I did... And I hope it'll work for you...

**Comment by [djtubig-malicex](https://answers.ros.org/users/4667/djtubig-malicex/) on 2013-04-16**:
Found the solution to the problem.  This is what happens when you install drivers over existing ones that worked, with ones that don't work. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After exploring Stephane.M's suggestion of reinstallation, it turns out the fault was an unintentional curiosity that killed everything.

The culprit:
[OpenNI-compliant SensorKinect Linux-x64 driver on the OpenNI website](http://www.openni.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/Sensor-Bin-Linux-x64-v5.1.2.1.tar.zip)

The cure:
[Avin2 GitHub snapshot of SensorKinect drivers](https://github.com/avin2/SensorKinect/zipball/unstable) - look in Bin folder and use the package relevant to your OS to install the driver.

Despite having a very similar version number, it appears the current SensorKinect build on the github works fine, while the one on the OpenNI website broke any application attempting to use the Kinect.  If problems persist running the install script, do a  `sudo ./install.sh -u` first before installing.

I hope this is a solution to anyone out there that curiously tried to install the OpenNI driver only to find it breaks something. :)

---

Originally posted by [djtubig-malicex](https://answers.ros.org/users/4667/djtubig-malicex/) with karma: 176 on 2013-04-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 11

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MichaelKorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/905/michaelkorn/) on 2013-04-16**:
not perfect, but the best openni version I ever used. The XnSensorServer needs a few seconds to terminate after stopping my program (I have to wait before I can restart), but it works.

**Comment by [Stephane.M](https://answers.ros.org/users/3548/stephane.m/) on 2013-04-16**:
Oh ! Good if you didn't had to reinstall :-) And now you gave this solution, it's true that I also had this problem, so reinstalling must have solved it.... I always install avin2 now :-)
Have a good day !

**Comment by [djtubig-malicex](https://answers.ros.org/users/4667/djtubig-malicex/) on 2013-04-16**:
Yeah, I was actually toying on the idea of falling back to a LiveUSB installation if reinstallation were the case.  If it weren't for the guide on this page for clues I probably would have done so: http://igorbarbosa.com/articles/how-to-install-kin-in-linux-mint-12-ubuntu/

**Comment by [CarolineQ](https://answers.ros.org/users/4109/carolineq/) on 2013-04-16**:
I followed the same step and it works for me as well ! Very nice ! Thanks !

**Comment by [mysteriousmonkey29](https://answers.ros.org/users/9531/mysteriousmonkey29/) on 2014-04-14**:
I ran into this problem a couple weeks ago after updating to ROS hydro.  I have followed these steps, but this does not seem to be the problem.  Is it likely I screwed up the installation, or could this problem be caused by something else?

**Comment by [ish45](https://answers.ros.org/users/20021/ish45/) on 2014-08-31**:
Can you please tell me how to run the install script on Ubuntu 12.04? I have downloaded the zip file, but which commands should I use in Ubuntu to install the file.

**Comment by [isura](https://answers.ros.org/users/1583/isura/) on 2014-10-13**:
@ish45 assuming you have Ubuntu 12.04 64bit:

```
cd ~/Downloads
unzip avin2-SensorKinect-v0.93-5.1.2.1-0-g15f1975.zip 
cd avin2-SensorKinect-15f1975/Bin
tar -xjf SensorKinect093-Bin-Linux-x64-v5.1.2.1.tar.bz2
cd Sensor-Bin-Linux-x64-v5.1.2.1
sudo ./install.sh
```

**Comment by [ingcavh](https://answers.ros.org/users/20373/ingcavh/) on 2014-10-14**:
Wow!!!!!! That worked for me, thanks a lot !!!!!

**Comment by [AlexR](https://answers.ros.org/users/21013/alexr/) on 2015-02-26**:
this helped me a lot. Thanks

Alex

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

FYI, I had this same issue.  I think I screwed up things when I was trying differnt drivers to get the Primesense Carmine working and then my Kinect stopped working. I ended up just reinstalling all libopenni via Synaptic and it started working again.

---

Originally posted by [TFinleyosu](https://answers.ros.org/users/4405/tfinleyosu/) with karma: 385 on 2013-11-26

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kleinsplash](https://answers.ros.org/users/5014/kleinsplash/) on 2014-01-13**:
You biscuit - I have been looking everywhere and this solved it.. unreal..

**Comment by [TFinleyosu](https://answers.ros.org/users/4405/tfinleyosu/) on 2014-02-07**:
I've never been called a biscuit before... not sure what it means even...

**Comment by [kleinsplash](https://answers.ros.org/users/5014/kleinsplash/) on 2014-02-09**:
Weell in that case: http://www.southafrica.info/travel/advice/saenglish.htm#.Uvh9Gvjzsak - you will notice that Ubuntu is also described..